# ¿April's fool o Día de los Santos Inocentes?

Tags: soporte

Hasta donde llega mi experiencia, StackOverflow realiza dos eventos a lo largo del año, los Sombreros de Invierno ([Winter Bash](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/)) y el [Día de las bromas de abril](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADa_de_las_bromas_de_abril).

Mientras que la <strike>odiosa</strike> Navidad se celebra en muchos de los países que concentran muchos usuarios de SO no sucede lo mismo con el *April's Fool*.

En algunos países de habla española el día de las bromas no es el primero de Abril si no el 28 de Diciembre (¡Este mes!).

Según la [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADa_de_los_Santos_Inocentes):

> En Hispanoamérica es costumbre realizar en esta fecha bromas de toda índole. Los medios de comunicación hacen bromas o tergiversan su contenido de tal modo que la información parezca real. Se trata de una libertad que se dan los agentes mediáticos para dar rienda suelta a su sentido del humor, oportunidad que solamente tienen una vez al año. Es tradición que los periódicos publiquen páginas enteras de noticias cómicas, con la advertencia de que es día de los inocentes, que van desde las que son una obvia mofa a cualquier suceso reciente, hasta las que parecen serias y engañan al lector desprevenido. El día de los inocentes se vive en todo el mundo hispanohablante.

Así que la pregunta es:

**¿SOes conmemorará el *April's fool* o el *Día de los Santos Inocentes*?**

Por un lado tener dos eventos el mismo mes puede ser divertido y a la vez excesivo. Por otro lado no tener eventos el resto de meses puede ser "*aburrido*".

Comment: Ojalá y si hagan uno :). Por otro lado, tengan cuidado en postear algo ese día, puedo dar una respuesta falsa xD.

Answer (score 5):

Me gusta esta idea pero la realidad es que por ahora no podremos tener dos actividades en vivo a la misma vez.  ¡Vamos a guardar esta idea para el futuro!

Comment: ¿Qué idea te gusta? ¿La de Abril o la de Diciembre? Entiendo que como Hispanoamericanos y Españoles lo propio sería Diciembre.

Comment: Sí, lo propio sería en diciembre, por eso comente que desafortunadamente no podemos tener dos eventos en vivo a la vez.

Comment: Así pues, ¿vamos a tener bromas en Abril? <:)

Comment: Solamente lo planeado para el sitio en inglés por ahora. ;)