# BUMP ¿Primero de abril o vigesimoctavo de diciembre?

Tags: discusión

La pregunta [está repetida](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1202/aprils-fool-o-d%C3%ADa-de-los-santos-inocentes). Los [BUMP](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bump) están prohibidos en esta red. Pero no ha habido resolución ni pronunciamiento en tres años.

La comunidad SOes es diferente a la comunidad SOen, ya tenemos nuestra propia trayectoria, estamos consolidados a nuestra manera y el sitio tiene un *regusto* diferente. También es diferente el sitio por usar un lenguaje diferente y en consecuencia tener una cultura diferente.

Llegados a este punto debemos plantearnos si podemos y/o queremos tener nuestros eventos web propios, y ahí es donde entra la idea del 28 de Diciembre como distinción de SOes.

En algunos países de habla española el día de las bromas no es el primero de Abril si no [el 28 de Diciembre](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%ADa_de_los_Santos_Inocentes):

> En Hispanoamérica es costumbre realizar en esta fecha bromas de toda índole. Los medios de comunicación hacen bromas o tergiversan su contenido de tal modo que la información parezca real. Se trata de una libertad que se dan los agentes mediáticos para dar rienda suelta a su sentido del humor, oportunidad que solamente tienen una vez al año. Es tradición que los periódicos publiquen páginas enteras de noticias cómicas, con la advertencia de que es día de los inocentes, que van desde las que son una obvia mofa a cualquier suceso reciente, hasta las que parecen serias y engañan al lector desprevenido. El día de los inocentes se vive en todo el mundo hispanohablante.

Reformulo la pregunta:

- ¿Queremos que SOes *celebre* los Santos Inocentes en lugar de el April Fool?

Comment: ¿Le repreguntaste al CM en la pregunta original para ver si ahora sí estamos preparados?

Comment: No pregunté. Respondió con un [tal vez más adelante](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1204/2742) pero no supe nada más.

Comment: No hablo de tener dos eventos iguales en fechas distintas si no cambiar un evento (mayormente anglosajón) por otro (mayormente hispano) dejando de hacer el primero y pasando a hacer el segundo..

Comment: Repito: **no es hacer algo diferente**. Es cambiar de fecha el día de las bromas.

Comment: Interesante lectura: [How do I get attention for old, unfixed bug reports and feature requests without official responses here on Meta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306397/209901)

Comment: Podrías intentarlo esta vez con nuestro CM, que en estos momentos es [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564240/nicolas-chabanovsky)